# Perfect forwarding c++

Tags: c++

Is this correct way to use `std::forward`?

```
struct Command {
public:
  int32_t uniqueID{0};

public:
  Command() = default;
  
  template<typename T>
  Command(T&& _uniqueID) : uniqueID(std::forward<int32_t>(_uniqueID)) //
  {
    //
  }
};
```

Or I should use this line?

```
Command(T&& _uniqueID) : uniqueID(std::forward<T>(_uniqueID))
```

Comment: No, _uniqueID have no move constructor/default constructor -> std::forwarding have no meaning .https://drewcampbell92.medium.com/understanding-move-semantics-and-perfect-forwarding-part-3-65575d523ff8

Comment: @long.kl apart from the current code, is it correct to use a concrete type as template parameters of std::forward<...>

Comment: fwiw, if you'd call some other function with the forwarded arg then it can make sense to use `std::forward` even if the type cannot be moved, because the function may be overloaded

Comment: @long.kl There actually might be cases where initialization of even `int32_t` by lvalue and rvalue have different effects. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/v7K4oGo8b.

Comment: @Max Can you please unaccept my answer. It is wrong and I don't have time to fix it.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, I don't know that , Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this correct way to use std::forward?

No, there's no point to use `std::forward` here. Moving a primitive type is same as copying it. I recommend following:

```
Command(std::int32_t _uniqueID) : uniqueID(_uniqueID) {}
```

Or alternatively, let the class be an aggregate:

```
struct Command {
    std::int32_t uniqueID{0};
};
```

Comment: How do you know that `T` is a primitive type in OP's case?

Comment: @DanielLangr `std::int32_t` is a primitive type. A non-primitive type can be converted into `std::int32_t` before initialising `Command`.

Comment: Yes, but the conversion may behave differently for lvalues and rvalues: https://godbolt.org/z/v7K4oGo8b

Comment: @DanielLangr Can you give a _practical_ example where someone does that?

Comment: @PasserBy No (and, I actually hope there is no such one ;). I'm just saying that it's possible.

Comment: @DanielLangr And the behaviour will be the same with both of my suggested solutions: https://godbolt.org/z/qMWKaq88x